# Google Chrome jQuery Animation lag in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, animation, position

I need to move an object smoothly with jQuery. I am using the `.animate()` method. I am animating it's `position` property. It pretty much works everywhere but the element isn't animated smoothly in Chrome.

```js
$('#element').animate({
    'left': '+=' + 400 + 'px'
}, 800);
```

How should it be animated correctly?

Comment: The animation starts from the left side of the screen instead of starting from the center, where the element is ...

Comment: have you tried animating the margin of wrap? as that's what's giving it's initial position.

Comment: @frank Post it as an answer. It might work. I'll accept it. ;)
You deserve some reputation for the precious help ...

Comment: I'll upload it in a few hours, if you want to see it working ...

Comment: Uploaded!
http://beta.aisnsim.com/login.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating the margin seems to do the work. Just use:

```
$('#login').animate({
    'margin-left': '+='+screen.width*2+'px'
}, 800, function(){ $('#login').addClass('inv'); });
$('#register').animate({
    'margin-left': '-150px'
}, 800);
```